# How to access hole behind kitchen cabinets?

Tags: cabinets, kitchen-counters, patching-drywall, countertops, hole-repair

**Description:**
I have cabinets that run along the left hand side of the kitchen. They meet in a corner, where they turn to meet my stove. Within that corner there is no shelving. Just an empty space underneath a countertop. (*pictures included*)
Also within this empty space, is a hole I need to seal.

**Why I'm concerned:**
I live in Florida, where palmetto bugs are unfortunately "normal". However if you don't have any holes in your home, you rarely see them. In my new apartment, I see about 2-3 a month, which is too many for me. I knew there must be a hole somewhere. Sure enough (when I pulled out my dishwasher and stove) I found a 3 inch gap between the wall and floor where trim should have been. I sealed the holes.
A few months later, I am still finding palmetto bugs here and there.
I am 99% sure the same gap runs behind the empty cabinet area I can't seem to reach.

**Question:** In the picture you can see how the countertop has a triangle cut out. I'm wondering if I can somehow remove just that section of the countertop in order to access the hole? If not, any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I would not remove the counter top I would pull the stove out and examine the face of the dead space area.  it would be much easier to open that area up and then conceal any cutting if it is needed because the area is hidden by the stove.

Comment: I missed it on first read......"my new apartment".    Most landlords offer some type of pest control.    But certainly consult them before doing anything drastic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my kitchen has a similar corner and it has a cupboard with turning pull-out shelves which make use of the dead space that you have.

So consider taking the nearest cupboard out then dealing with the holes and putting better cupboards back in.

Comment: Please do not attempt to remove that triangle of counter.....they should be held together by clamps under the seam....very likely not going to come out by itself.    Plus whole counter is screwed onto the corners of the cabinets from underneath.

Comment: @LimoDRIVER don’t think I suggested removing the counter did I? And as you point out the screws go in from underneath so they can usually be accessed. So what’s wring with my suggestion? Do you actually have a better one?

Comment: Mike I think the limo driver meant to put it as a comment on the answer I almost seconded it down below. Then realized it was below your answer.

Comment: My apologies,  no offense meant to anyone